# Spring Cloud Gateway Token Relay: who is the OAuth2 client?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm exploring the TokenRelay filter of Spring Cloud Gateway in order to mediate between a SAML2 Session and OAuth2 Tokens (More on this in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75235338/use-oauth2-for-authorization-of-session-authenticated-users)).

I've tried to figure this out myself but I can't seem to sort it out: using this filter, **who is the OAuth2 client**?

I was expecting this to be the gateway itself, hence a confidential one.. but in my initial setup I see calls for the authorization code in the browser and I don't understand if this is the expected behavior or not.

If it's indeed how it's supposed to work and the Browser carries out the token exchange, does this mean that the client cannot be confidential? Should I switch to PKCE?

I might sound a little confused (I really am!) but I can't seem to find much about the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In BFF pattern, the only OAuth2 client is the BFF itself (spring-cloud-gateway in your case), but in authorization-code flow the user authenticates with its user-agent (most frequently system browser for login forms but could be other apps for biometry or multi-factor auth). However, the authorization-code should be sent by authorization-server only to declared clients: the BFF (not the rich app in browser) which will use it to fetch OAuth2 tokens.

To be clearer (maybe):

1. authorization-code generation is triggered by a request from the user-agent (browser) to the authorization-server
2. the authorization-server sends the code to the client (spring-cloud-gateway BFF)
3. the client (spring-cloud-gateway BFF) uses the code to fetch tokens from the authorization-server

=> with this pattern, the browser never sees the OAuth2 tokens (nor the authorization-code).

Of course, this is not the same when the declared OAuth2 client is a public client running in the browser (code and tokens are still sent to the client but as it is running in the browser, tokens are stored in ... the browser)

#### Edit: I published [a tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2)

With sample implementations for Angular, React (Nex.js) and Vue

Comment: Just like I imagined... I must have a look and figure out why the gateway is sending the redirect back from the authorization server to the browser instead of following it itself...

Comment: Looking at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2#1-spring-cloud-gateway-as-an-oauth-20-client i see the browser being involved in the authorization process... is this still secure even without PKCE?

Comment: I just added a BFF tutorial to my repo: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff